# SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm having an issue. When I submit a form on development server it works as expected. When I deploy the application (**`asp.net core 2.1 mvc app`**) and try to submit the form it hangs for a good while then I get a blank page with status code 500.

Any clue as to what that's all about?

Below is my most recent addition of code in the project. It submits a form and sends the results via email. I am using ReCapcha if that makes any difference at all?

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactMe([FromForm] Contact model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (!await GoogleRecaptchaHelper.IsReCaptchaPassedAsync(Request.Form["g-recaptcha-response"],
                _configuration["GoogleReCaptcha:secret"]))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You failed the CAPTCHA");
                TempData["message"] = $"Sorry {model.SenderName}, You failed the CAPTCHA";
                TempData["messageClass"] = "alert alert-danger";
                return View("Contact", model);
            }


            try
            {
                var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = "auth.smtp.1and1.co.uk",
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"no-reply@griffithswebdesign.com", "totimen"),

                };
                using (var message = new MailMessage("no-reply@griffithswebdesign.com", "michael@griffithswebdesign.com")
                {
                    Subject = "Message from " + model.SenderName + " - ROOTWORKS Website",
                    ReplyToList = { new MailAddress(model.SenderEmail) },
                    IsBodyHtml = true,
                    Body = "<h2 style=\"text-align:center\">Message from ROOTWORKS</h2><p><strong>From:</strong> " + model.SenderName + "</p><p>" + model.MessageContent + "</p>"
                })
                {
                    smtpClient.Send(message);
                    TempData["message"] = $"Thank you {model.SenderName}, your message has been sent and someone will be in touch soon.";
                    TempData["messageClass"] = "alert alert-success";

                }
                
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                TempData["message"] = $"Sorry {model.SenderName}, something has gone wrong and your message has not been sent. Please try again later.";
                TempData["messageClass"] = "alert alert-danger";

            }

            return RedirectToRoute("contactroute");


        }
        return RedirectToRoute("contactroute");
    }
    
}
```

******************EDIT****************************

That was in my controller.
I also have a helper for google recapcha

```
 using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Rootworks.Helpers
{
    public static class GoogleRecaptchaHelper
    {
        // A function that checks reCAPTCHA results
        public static async Task<bool> IsReCaptchaPassedAsync(string gRecaptchaResponse, string secret)
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("secret", secret),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("response", gRecaptchaResponse)
            });
            var res = await httpClient.PostAsync($"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify", content);
            if (res.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return false;
            }

            string JSONres = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic JSONdata = JObject.Parse(JSONres);
            if (JSONdata.success != "true")
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

On further investigation I found I am getting the following error:

> SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected
> party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
> connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
> System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Also, here is my startup.cs code - in case there's something going on there:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;


namespace Rootworks
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; private set; }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            this.HostingEnvironment = env;
            this.Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
            services.AddSession();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //if (env.IsDevelopment())
            //{
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            //}
            //app.UseHsts();
            app.UseSession();
            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
            
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: null,
                    template: "about-smp",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "Aboutsmp" }
                    );
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: null,
                    template: "the-founder",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "Aboutfounder" }
                    );
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: null,
                    template: "how-rootworks-are-different",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "Whyme" }
                    );
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: null,
                    template: "the-treatments",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "Treatments" }
                    );
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "contactroute",
                    template: "contact",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "ContactMe" }
                    );
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name:null,
                    template:"faq",
                    defaults: new { Controller = "Home", action = "FAQ"}
                    );
                routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });


            });
            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the ReCaptcha require you to specify the domain or address from which it will accept requests? If so, make sure you add or change it to include the deployment server. Last time I used ReCaptcha, I think I had to specify allowed domains/addresses. The SocketException sounds like it's just timing out, possibly because your request is being blocked.